# Is it possible to have a wiki inside a site?

Tags: html, mediawiki

Lets say I have a site with many pages..One of them is a page called projects where say students will write about their projects. Can I have a wiki JUST for this page which will have the same theme as the rest of the pages? Can I put the whole thing in a frame?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I have a wiki JUST for this page

Yes. You'll just need to find, or write, some wiki software then configure your server to use it for that URI. The specifics depends on your server and language of choice.

> which will have the same theme as the rest of the pages?

So long as the software you use gives you sufficient control over the template

> Can I put the whole thing in a frame?

Yes, but why? And "Eugh!".

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Im using media wiki. Wont there be a problem with the theme?

Comment: No, MediaWiki's theme can be fully customized.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iframe (Inline frame) for this, but it would seem easier to me to just code the page yourself using PHP and a relational DBMS (such as MySQL), since it's really just one page and should be relatively easy to implement.

Comment: Its not one page.. Users should be able to create and edit their own pages.. That should take a lot of time to code. Since media wiki does exactly that im using it..